# hp pavilion 15-cs3010la boot device not found, enabling legacy option didn't work

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I've been almost a year with Ubuntu 20.04 installed, yesterday my screen froze, had to do a hard reset and when it rebooted, I got the error message. Most of the solutions I found says that enabling the legacy setting in the bios settings the problem but not in my case.... Is there anything I can do?

Edit:

```
sudo fdisk -l
isk /dev/loop0: 2.1 GiB, 2160009216 bytes, 4218768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.45 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 50.98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 27.26 GiB, 29260513280 bytes, 57149440 sectors
Disk model: INTEL HBRPEKNX0202AHO                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/sda: 28.84 GiB, 30943995904 bytes, 60437492 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2cf4ba3a

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          0  5999871  5999872  2.9G  0 Empty
/dev/sda2       5271500  5279499     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       6000640 60437491 54436852   26G 83 Linux
```

and

```
sudo lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0    2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1     7:1    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop2     7:2    0  219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop3     7:3    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop4     7:4    0   51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop5     7:5    0 65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
sda       8:0    1 28.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    1  2.9G  0 part /cdrom
├─sda2    8:2    1  3.9M  0 part 
└─sda3    8:3    1   26G  0 part /var/crash
nvme1n1 259:0    0 27.3G  0 disk /media/ubuntu/4E28B9EC3D2EDE53
```

Comment: If a boot device is suddenly not found, it could point to a hardware failure. Grab your Ubuntu installation USB (or DVD) and boot into a live session. See if the storage device is discoverable. If it is, you may be able to mount the device and check the error logs (or recover data) 

Comment: I did that, but the live USB gets frozen when I choose "try Ubuntu"

Comment: This is pointing more towards hardware failure. Do you have another bootable USB you can try (any OS, really) just to verify that your machine can complete a boot sequence? 

Comment: I tried another Ubuntu stick and I could "try Ubuntu" but I cannot see my drive

Comment: I can only see a 28 gb disk on /dev/nvme1n1 which is empty...

Comment: Based on [the spec sheet](https://support.hp.com/uy-es/document/c06455233) for your notebook, that leaves about 450GB of addressable space unaccounted for. Can you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo lsblk`?

Comment: @matigo added the requested to the question

Comment: That ... looks like a device failure to me. SSDs don't usually fail this way, though. Were you using encrypted volumes?

Comment: nop, nothing encrypted... i just installed ubuntu a year ago, installed the software I use, themes, etc, and nothing else...